# JColorChooser get components

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jcolorchooser

I'm trying to implement a custom `JColorChooser`.

```
colorPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JColorChooser tcc = new JColorChooser();
    AbstractColorChooserPanel [] panels = tcc.getChooserPanels();
    for(AbstractColorChooserPanel p : panels){
        if(p.getDisplayName().equals("RVB")){
                colorPanel.add(p);
        }
    }

    final JDialog j = new JDialog(jframe, true);
    j.setSize(800, 300);
    j.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,2));
    createListColor();
    j.add(colorPanel);
```

This works well and show me the following :

[image]

No i'm stuck on how I can get the listeners for the widgets because the problem is that the panel isn't created by me. How can I get the components (`TextField`, etc.) of the `AbstractColorChooserPanel p` ?

How can I catch the events on the widgets and how can I get the value of the textFields in the component?

Comment: See also [*Creating a Custom Chooser Panel*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any API to get the individual components.

You can use Darryls' [SwingUtils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) to access the components on any panel.

Comment: So what's the interest of the JColorChooser if we can't interact with it ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson So I have to create my custom panel as a subclass of `AbstractColorChooserPanel` ?

Comment: If you want to create a custom panel, then yes. Read the tutorial link that @trashgod provided in the comment section.

Comment: since is possible, but why bothering with, enless kudos to Darryl :-)